Generic C++ Class to Associate enum Values with Strings for Translation
This is the first time I am using C++ templates in a very long time, and is the first time I have created a template class.
When developing projects I often run into a common problem: I have an enum that I need strings for, either for display purposes or for testing and debugging. In the project I'm currently developing, I encountered this for 2 different enums. Initially I created 2 different classes to do the translation using 2 different implementations. I am now trying to refactor that code to reduce the amount of code in the project (currently 1530 lines of code). I initially used std::map in one of the implementations, but, in a previous review I was informed that there is a cost to using std::map.
I would ask if there were memory leaks, but Valgrind assures me there are no memory leaks. Running Valgrind did help find 2 errors in the code that have been corrected.
The code provided is a standalone unit test.
Questions I'd appreciate answers to:

Using the C++ 20 standard, are there any additional features that I can use to reduce the amount of code needed in either the DictionaryBase class or any of its sub-classes.
Can performance or memory usage be optimized?
Could you maintain the code?
Are the naming conventions clear or should some of the class and method names be changed?
What would be the highest maintenance cost if you needed to maintain this code?

Development Environment

C++ 20
CMake
GCC 12
Ubuntu 22.04
Visual Studio Code (vscode)

The Code
The GitHub repository for this code. It includes a CMakeLists.txt file if you want to build and run the test. For the exact files presented in this question you want the PreCoddeReview branch. Based on the reviews I am making changes which will be pushed to the master.
AbstractDictionary.h
#ifndef ABSTRACTDICTIONARY_H_
#define ABSTRACTDICTIONARY_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

/*
 * This abstract class provides a basic conversion of enums or integers to strings.
 * More complex objects than strings are also supported, however, overrides will
 * be necessary;
 * 
 * Enums or integers should have an illegal value as 0. If not, then override the
 * getIds method.
 */
template <typename dicID, typename dicName>
class DictionaryBase
{
public:
    virtual dicID getIds(dicName itemName) noexcept
    {
        dicID foundID = static_cast<dicID>(0);

        auto definition = std::find_if(searchTable.begin(), searchTable.end(),
            [&itemName](struct DictType &dicItem) {return (dicItem.names == itemName);});

        if (definition != searchTable.end())
        {
            foundID = definition->id;
        }

        return foundID;
    };
    virtual dicName getNames(dicID id) noexcept
    {
        dicName nameFound;

        auto definition = std::find_if(searchTable.begin(), searchTable.end(),
            [&id](struct DictType &dicItem) {return (dicItem.id == id);});

        if (definition != searchTable.end())
        {
            nameFound = definition->names;
        }

        return nameFound;
    }
    virtual bool noOverRidesNeed() noexcept = 0;

protected:
    struct DictType
    {
        dicID id;
        dicName names;
    };
    std::vector<DictType> searchTable;
    void addDefinition(dicID inId, dicName inName) noexcept
    {
        DictType newDef(inId, inName);
        searchTable.push_back(newDef);
    }


};

#endif // ABSTRACTDICTIONARY_H_#include <algorithm>

ColumnDictionary.cpp
#include "ColumnDictionary.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

ColumnDictionary::ColumnDictionary()
{
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::DATE, "Date");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::TEMPERATURE, "Temperature");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::PUSLE_RATE, "Pulse Rate");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::RESPIRATION_RATE, "Respiration Rate");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::BLOOD_PRESSURE, "Blood Pressure");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::BLOOD_OXYGEN, "Blood Oxygen");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::WEIGHT, "Weight");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::BLOOD_SUGAR, "Blood Glucose");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::EXERCISE, "Exercise");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::SLEEP_HOURS, "Sleep Hours");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::SLEEP_INTERRUPTIONS, "Sleep Interruptions");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::BOWEL_MOVEMENTS, "Bowel Movements");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_CALORIES, "Calories");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_SATURATED_FAT, "Saturated Fat");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_TRANS_FAT, "Trans Fat");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_CHOLESTEROL, "Cholesterol");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_SODIUM, "Sodium");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_FIBER, "Fiber");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_TOTAL_SUGARS, "Total Sugars");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_PROTIEN, "Protien");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_VITAMIN_D, "Vitamin D");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_CALCIUM, "Calcium");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_IRON, "Iron");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NUTRITION_POTASSIUM, "Potassium");
    addDefinition(ColumnIds::NOTES, "Notes");
}

ColumnDictionary.h
#ifndef COLUMNDICTIONARY_H_
#define COLUMNDICTIONARY_H_

#include "AbstractDictionary.h"
#include "columnidenum.h"
#include <string>

class ColumnDictionary : public DictionaryBase<ColumnIds, std::string>
{
    public:
    ColumnDictionary();
    ~ColumnDictionary() = default;
    bool noOverRidesNeed() noexcept override { return true; }
};

#endif //COLUMNDICTIONARY_H_

columnidenum.h
#ifndef COLUMNIDENUM_H
#define COLUMNIDENUM_H

/*
 * This enum is for use in selecting column names to display and the order of
 * the comlumns in the table display.
 */
enum class ColumnIds
{
    NO_COLUMN,
    DATE,
    // Vital Signs
    TEMPERATURE,
    PUSLE_RATE,
    RESPIRATION_RATE,
    BLOOD_PRESSURE,
    BLOOD_OXYGEN,
    WEIGHT,
    BLOOD_SUGAR,
    // Other things that might affect vital signs
    EXERCISE,
    SLEEP_HOURS,
    SLEEP_INTERRUPTIONS,
    BOWEL_MOVEMENTS,
    // Nutritional Information
    NUTRITION_CALORIES,
    NUTRITION_SATURATED_FAT,
    NUTRITION_TRANS_FAT,
    NUTRITION_CHOLESTEROL,
    NUTRITION_SODIUM,
    NUTRITION_FIBER,
    NUTRITION_TOTAL_SUGARS,
    NUTRITION_PROTIEN,
    NUTRITION_VITAMIN_D,
    NUTRITION_CALCIUM,
    NUTRITION_IRON,
    NUTRITION_POTASSIUM,
    NOTES,
    LAST_COLUMN_ID
};

#endif // COLUMNIDENUM_H

TableDictionary.cpp
#include <string>
#include "TableDictionary.h"
#include <utility>

TableDictionary::TableDictionary()
{
    addDefinition(TableIds::TEMPURATURE, {"Tempurature", "tmp"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::REPIRATION_RATE, {"RepirationRate", "resp"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::BLOOD_PRESSURE, {"BloodPressure", "bp"});;
    addDefinition(TableIds::BLOOD_OXYGEN, {"BloodOxygen", "bo"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::WEIGHT, {"Weight", "wt"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::BLOOD_SUGAR, {"BloodSugar", "bg"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::EXERCISE, {"Exercise", "exer"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::SLEEP, {"Sleep", "slp"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::BOWEL_MOVEMENTS, {"BowlMovements", "bm"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::NUTRITION, {"Nutrition", "nut"});
    addDefinition(TableIds::NOTES, {"Notes", "nts"});
}

std::string TableDictionary::getShortName(TableIds key) noexcept
{
    return getNames(key).second;
}

std::string TableDictionary::getTableName(TableIds key) noexcept
{
    return getNames(key).first;
}

TableIds TableDictionary::getId(std::string key) noexcept
{
    TableIds id = TableIds::NO_TABLE;

    auto definition = std::find_if(searchTable.begin(), searchTable.end(),
        [&key](struct DictType &dicItem) {
            return (dicItem.names.first == key ||
            dicItem.names.second == key);
        });

    if (definition != searchTable.end())
    {
        id = definition->id;
    }

    return id;
}

TableDictionary.h
#ifndef TABLEDICTIONARY_H
#define TABLEDICTIONARY_H

#include "AbstractDictionary.h"
#include <string>
#include "tableidenum.h"
#include <utility>

class TableDictionary : public DictionaryBase<TableIds, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>
{
public:
    TableDictionary();
    ~TableDictionary() = default;
    bool noOverRidesNeed() noexcept override { return false; }
    std::string getShortName(TableIds id) noexcept;
    std::string getTableName(TableIds key) noexcept;
    TableIds getId(std::string name) noexcept;
};

#endif

tableidenum.h
#ifndef TABLEIDENUM_H
#define TABLEIDENUM_H

enum class TableIds
{
    NO_TABLE,
    TEMPURATURE,
    REPIRATION_RATE,
    BLOOD_PRESSURE,     // Currently Blood Pressure and Pulse Rate
    BLOOD_OXYGEN,
    WEIGHT,
    BLOOD_SUGAR,
    EXERCISE,
    SLEEP,
    BOWEL_MOVEMENTS,
    NUTRITION,
    NOTES,
    LAST_TABLE_ID
};

#endif // TABLEIDENUM_H

TestDictionary.cpp
#include "AbstractDictionary.h"
#include "ColumnDictionary.h"
#include "columnidenum.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TableDictionary.h"
#include <vector>

/*
 * Testing the basic implementation.
 */
enum class BaseTestEnum
{
    BASETEST_INVALID,
    BASETEST_1,
    BASETEST_2,
    BASETEST_3,
    BASETEST_LAST
};

class BaseTestClass : public DictionaryBase<BaseTestEnum, std::string>
{
public:
    BaseTestClass()
    {
        addDefinition(BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_1, "Base Test 1");    
        addDefinition(BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_2, "Base Test 2");    
        addDefinition(BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_3, "Base Test 3");    
    }
    ~BaseTestClass() = default;
    bool noOverRidesNeed() noexcept override { return true; }
};

static bool BaseTestIdToName(BaseTestEnum input, std::string expectedOutput)
{
    BaseTestClass underTest;
    std::string actualOutPut = underTest.getNames(input);

    if (!expectedOutput.compare(actualOutPut) == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "\tBase ID to Name Test Failed " << expectedOutput << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool BaseTestNameToID(std::string input, BaseTestEnum expectedOutput)
{
    BaseTestClass underTest;
    BaseTestEnum actualOutPut = underTest.getIds(input);

    if (expectedOutput != actualOutPut)
    {
        std::cerr << "\tBase Name to ID Test Failed " << input << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool basicTestIdsDictionary()
{
    bool testPassed = true;
    std::cout << "\nTesting base implementation\n";


    if (!BaseTestIdToName(BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_1, "Base Test 1"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!BaseTestIdToName(BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_2, "Base Test 2"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!BaseTestIdToName(BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_3, "Base Test 3"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!BaseTestNameToID("Base Test 1", BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_1))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!BaseTestNameToID("Base Test 2", BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_2))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!BaseTestNameToID("Base Test 3", BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_3))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Negative Test Path
    if (!BaseTestIdToName(static_cast<BaseTestEnum>(217), ""))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!BaseTestNameToID("Name Not Found", BaseTestEnum::BASETEST_INVALID))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return testPassed;
}

/*
 * Testing TableDictionary class which adds some extenstions to the base clase.
 */
static bool TableTestIdToName(TableIds input, std::pair<std::string, std::string>  expectedOutput)
{
    TableDictionary underTest;
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> actualOutPut(underTest.getNames(input));

    if (expectedOutput.first.compare(actualOutPut.first) != 0 || 
            expectedOutput.second.compare(actualOutPut.second) != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "\tTable ID to Name Test Failed  (" << expectedOutput.first << " " << expectedOutput.second << ")\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool TableTestNameToID(std::pair<std::string, std::string> input, TableIds expectedOutput)
{
    TableDictionary underTest;
    TableIds actualOutPut = underTest.getIds(input);

    if (expectedOutput != actualOutPut)
    {
        std::cerr << "\tTable Name to ID Test Failed (" << input.first << " " << input.second << ")\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool TableTestNameToID(std::string input, TableIds expectedOutput)
{
    TableDictionary underTest;
    TableIds actualOutPut = underTest.getId(input);

    if (expectedOutput != actualOutPut)
    {
        std::cerr << "\tSingle Table Name to ID Test Failed " << input << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
typedef struct TableIDTestData
{
    TableIds testID;
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> testNames;
} TableIDTestData;

static std::vector<TableIDTestData> TTestData =
{
    {TableIds::TEMPURATURE, {"Tempurature", "tmp"}},
    {TableIds::REPIRATION_RATE, {"RepirationRate", "resp"}},
    {TableIds::BLOOD_PRESSURE, {"BloodPressure", "bp"}},
    {TableIds::BLOOD_OXYGEN, {"BloodOxygen", "bo"}},
    {TableIds::WEIGHT, {"Weight", "wt"}},
    {TableIds::BLOOD_SUGAR, {"BloodSugar", "bg"}},
    {TableIds::EXERCISE, {"Exercise", "exer"}},
    {TableIds::SLEEP, {"Sleep", "slp"}},
    {TableIds::BOWEL_MOVEMENTS, {"BowlMovements", "bm"}},
    {TableIds::NUTRITION, {"Nutrition", "nut"}},
    {TableIds::NOTES, {"Notes", "nts"}},
};

static bool testTableIdsDictionary()
{
    bool testPassed = true;

    std::cout << "\nTesting TableDictionary\n";

    for (auto testCandidate: TTestData)
    {
        if (!TableTestIdToName(testCandidate.testID, testCandidate.testNames))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!TableTestNameToID(testCandidate.testNames, testCandidate.testID))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!TableTestNameToID(testCandidate.testNames.first, testCandidate.testID))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!TableTestNameToID(testCandidate.testNames.second, testCandidate.testID))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Negative Test Path
    if (!TableTestIdToName(static_cast<TableIds>(217), {"",""}))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!TableTestNameToID(std::pair("Name Not Found", "bad"), TableIds::NO_TABLE))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!TableTestNameToID("Name Not Found", TableIds::NO_TABLE))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return testPassed;
}

/*
 * Testing the ColumnDictionary class, which just uses the base class.
 */
static bool ColumnTestIdToName(ColumnIds input, std::string expectedOutput)
{
    ColumnDictionary underTest;
    std::string actualOutPut = underTest.getNames(input);

    if (!expectedOutput.compare(actualOutPut) == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Column ID to Name Test Failed " << expectedOutput << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool ColumnTestNameToID(std::string input, ColumnIds expectedOutput)
{
    ColumnDictionary underTest;
    ColumnIds actualOutPut = underTest.getIds(input);

    if (expectedOutput != actualOutPut)
    {
        std::cerr << "\tColumn Name to ID Test Failed " << input << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

typedef struct CTestData
{
    ColumnIds testId;
    std::string testName;
} CTestData;

static std::vector<CTestData> positiveColumnTestData = 
{
    {ColumnIds::DATE, "Date"},
    {ColumnIds::TEMPERATURE, "Temperature"},
    {ColumnIds::PUSLE_RATE, "Pulse Rate"},
    {ColumnIds::RESPIRATION_RATE, "Respiration Rate"},
    {ColumnIds::BLOOD_PRESSURE, "Blood Pressure"},
    {ColumnIds::BLOOD_OXYGEN, "Blood Oxygen"},
    {ColumnIds::WEIGHT, "Weight"},
    {ColumnIds::BLOOD_SUGAR, "Blood Glucose"},
    {ColumnIds::EXERCISE, "Exercise"},
    {ColumnIds::SLEEP_HOURS, "Sleep Hours"},
    {ColumnIds::SLEEP_INTERRUPTIONS, "Sleep Interruptions"},
    {ColumnIds::BOWEL_MOVEMENTS, "Bowel Movements"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_CALORIES, "Calories"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_SATURATED_FAT, "Saturated Fat"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_TRANS_FAT, "Trans Fat"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_CHOLESTEROL, "Cholesterol"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_SODIUM, "Sodium"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_FIBER, "Fiber"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_TOTAL_SUGARS, "Total Sugars"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_PROTIEN, "Protien"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_VITAMIN_D, "Vitamin D"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_CALCIUM, "Calcium"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_IRON, "Iron"},
    {ColumnIds::NUTRITION_POTASSIUM, "Potassium"},
    {ColumnIds::NOTES, "Notes"}
};

static bool testColumnIdsDictionary()
{
    bool testPassed = true;
    std::cout << "\nTesting ColumnDictionary\n";

    for (auto testCandidate: positiveColumnTestData)
    {
        if (!ColumnTestIdToName(testCandidate.testId, testCandidate.testName))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!ColumnTestNameToID(testCandidate.testName, testCandidate.testId))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Negative Test Path
    if (!ColumnTestIdToName(static_cast<ColumnIds>(217), ""))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!ColumnTestNameToID("Name Not Found", ColumnIds::NO_COLUMN))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return testPassed;
}

int main()
{
    int exitStatus = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    if (!basicTestIdsDictionary())
    {
        exitStatus = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!testColumnIdsDictionary())
    {
        exitStatus = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!testTableIdsDictionary())
    {
        exitStatus = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << (exitStatus == EXIT_FAILURE ? "Tests Failed\n\n" : "All Tests Passed\n\n");

    return exitStatus;
}


For future reviews, I recommend presenting each header file before anything that includes it; that makes it easier to collect all the sources into a single translation unit for experimentation by reviewers.

@TobySpeight My mistake, sorry, .cpp comes before .h in cat src/* > CR_Question.txt. I meant to change the order, but didn't get to it.

It's not going to be perfect
Unfortunately, until we get true enum reflection in C++ (supposedly in C++26), any solution to map enum values to strings is going to have some issues. Your solution suffers from the following issues:

It's verbose. You have to write a lot of addDefinition(…) statements.
It doesn't automatically map enum names to strings, so you are repeating yourself, with possibilities of mistakes.
It doesn't catch missing definitions.
It doesn't report an error when you add two definitions for the same enum value.

The best way to handle this pre-C++26 is to use X macros, with the only drawback being the use of macros.
This is just a slow std::map
Really, the only thing DictionaryBase does is map between dicIDs and dicNames. However, since you store things in an unsorted std::vector, lookups are going to be \$O(N)\$. Why not just use a std::map for \$O(\log N)\$ lookups, or even better a std::unordered_map for \$O(1)\$ lookups:
template<typename dicID, typename dicName>
using DictionaryBase = std::unordered_map<dicID, dicName>;

Or if you do want to add some extra functionality, then at least use std::unordered_map internally.
There is a cost to these containers though, and that is that they allocate each item individually on the heap. That might be what the previous reviewers complained about. If that is important, then consider using std::vector, but then at least keeping it sorted, so you can use a binary search algorithm like std::equal_range() to do \$O(\log N)\$ lookups. In C++23 this is made easy with std::flat_map.
What is the point of noOverRidesNeed()?
I see this member function being defined, but it's never used. What is the purpose of this?
Is a virtual base class really needed?
I don't think it's very useful to make DictionaryBase a virtual base class. Are you really ever going to override the only two functions that make this base class useful? And why would you need to override them just to support a dicName more complex than a std::string? The only property you are using is that it has an equality operator, which is totally reasonable. And if that is not enough, then I would rather add another template parameter that can hold a custom comparator function, just like std::map does.
Add definitions in the constructor
Instead of having an addDefinition() that must be called multiple times, I would rather add a constructor that takes a std::initializer_list<DictType>, which should avoid typing and ensures all definitions are have to be added at construction time:
template <typename dicID, typename dicName>
class DictionaryBase
{
    …
public:
    DictionaryBase(std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions): searchTable(definitions) {}
    …
};

ColumnDictionary::ColumnDictionary(): DictionaryBase<ColumnIds, std::string>{
    {ColumnIds::DATE, "Date"},
    {ColumnIds::TEMPERATURE, "Temperature"},
    {ColumnIds::PUSLE_RATE, "Pulse Rate"},
    …
} {}


I was wondering if anyone would spot the noOverRidesNeed() hack. Originally the 2 other virtual functions that are implemented had no body, then I experimented with the implementation. The only way to keep the class abstract was to add noOverRidesNeed() with no body. Your discussion about is the abstract class necessary was already something I was considering.

You don't need a virtual = 0 member function to prevent the base class to be instantiated, you can also just make the base class's constructor protected.

Both you and @TobySpeight suggest that the data should be sorted. Should the sort be based on the value of the enum? I like some of your suggestions, I have branched the GitHub repository and will be making changes on the master.

@pacmaninbw It depends on which lookups you typically do. If you do both, you can even sort on both (using a second vector that references the first one to avoid having to store strings twice).

If you have the time you might want to look at the follow up question

Consider using magic enum instead. It basically automates this.
Alternatively, for example if you want other spellings for the string representations, I found X-macros very useful:
#define COLUMNIDS(X)                        \
    X(NO_COLUMN,        "None")             \
    X(DATE,             "Date")             \
    /* Vital Signs */                       \  
    X(TEMPERATURE,      "Temperature")      \
    X(PUSLE_RATE,       "Pulse Rate")       \
    X(RESPIRATION_RATE, "Respiration Rate") 
    // ...

enum class ColumnID {
    #define X(name, spelling) name,
    COLUMNIDS(X)
    #undef X
};

std::string toSpelling(ColumnID ID) {
    switch (ID) {
        #define X(name, spelling) \
            case ColumnID::name: return spelling;
        COLUMNIDS(X)
        #undef X
        default: return "";
    }
}

Not really C++ idiomatic, but it automates stuff that you can't otherwise automate.

indeed, this is one of the rare use cases where the preprocessor is really very useful.

I really like X macros in the form shown here, which I find demystifies the code a bit.

This is something I've had to do before (hopefully I won't need to do it again once I have a C++26 compiler).  Your implementation shares some of the design problems my early implementations had.
Mapping isn't necessarily complete
In this implementation, if we fail to insert the corresponding addDefinition() when we add an value to the enum, we get no warning at compilation time.
My preference is to use a switch for the enum⟶string (forward) conversion, because good compilers will warn if a case is missing.  We can build the reverse (string⟶enum) mapping by calling the forward function for each value (which may require a manual change, but we can guide implementers there from the switch).
static constexpr char* to_string(BaseTestEnum value)
{
    switch (value) {
    // values here should also be present in the
    // all_BaseTestEnum list
    case BASETEST_INVALID: return "invalid";
    ⋮
    case BASETEST_LAST: return "last";
    }
    // invalid value
    return nullptr;
}

static constexpr BaseTestEnum all_BaseTestEnum[] =
    { BASETEST_INVALID,
      BASETEST_1,
      BASETEST_2,
      BASETEST_3,
      BASETEST_LAST
    };

We can then provide the function and collection as a template arguments, and the template can build the reverse mapping from those.
Where we have short form and long form (as I do, where storage/interchange uses single words but display uses localised multi-word strings), then instantiate the template separately for each different to_string() function.
Invalid values don't round-trip consistently
When communicating with a different version of the program (either across the network or across time via data files), we may have to deal with values that we don't understand.  We could be a little more robust by falling back to numeric representation (via std::to_underlying()) when we fail to stringify a value.
Lookup table is unsorted
We should sort the table so that we can do O(log n) lookup instead of O(n).

Some other things I noticed in the implementation:

This find_if() is quite convoluted:

    auto definition = std::find_if(searchTable.begin(), searchTable.end(),
        [&itemName](struct DictType &dicItem) {return (dicItem.names == itemName);});


The constrained find() accepts a "projection" argument to simplify this:
     auto definition = std::ranges::find(searchTable, itemName, &DictType::names);


Assignment to a variable that's about to go out of scope:

    dicID foundID = static_cast<dicID>(0);

    if (definition != searchTable.end())
    {
        foundID = definition->id;
    }

    return foundID;


Would be simpler written without the variable as
        if (definition != searchTable.end())
        {
            return definition->id;
        }

        return static_cast<dicID>(0);


Quite a few of the classes have a destructor declared = default.  Whilst it's good that you're paying attention to destructors, these are better left unwritten.
On the other hand, given that DictionaryBase<> is intended to be inherited from, we do need to give it a destructor so that it can be virtual:
    virtual ~DictionaryBase() = default;

That said, I don't see a need for inheritance in solving this problem.



You have raised several good points. About inheritance, if you look at the TableDictionary you will see that some additional functionality has been added in the case where 2 strings might map to a single enum. How would you handle 2 different enum classes such as Column names and Table names that are using in the same larger class? For an example of how I will be using this, I will be replacing hdb_columnnames with ColumnDictionary and TableNameDictionarywithTableDictionary` in https://github.com/pacmaninbw/TestColumnMapModel.

I suggested using two separate instantiations to get your TableDictionary functionality - one that transforms to/from the short names and one to/from the longer (display?) names.

If you have the time you might want to look at the follow up question

I have created a chat room specifically for this question and related questions and for the answers to those questions. I'd like you to join the discussion. I find your answers quite educational.

Unlike other answers here, I do not believe reflection will solve these issues if you want to display the strings to the user. Enums are often shortened and does not contain a standard way of handling spacing and casing.
Now I did what you are accomplishing here before using C++11 only. It is much less verbose and can handle alternatives, case folding when reading. Here is how it is defined. First you define your regular enum:
enum class Days {
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
};

With a macro you simply define strings associated with each value:
DefineEnumStrings( Days,
    {Days::Monday, "Monday"},
    {Days::Tuesday, "Tuesday"},
    {Days::Wednesday, "Wednesday"},
    {Days::Thursday, "Thursday"},
    {Days::Friday, "Friday"},
    {Days::Saturday, "Saturday"},
    {Days::Sunday, "Sunday"}
    {Days::Monday, "Mon"},
    //...
);

That's all. You can stream insert and extract strings, it can be converted from/to string. Now what this system does is that it creates a new class using your definitions. However, by itself class is useless enum_tr_loc function is defined so that all supporting functions can find the class associated with the enum, remember this uses argument dependent lookup and does not require specific namespace. Only the definition and the enum should be in the same namespace.
#define DefineEnumStrings(type, ...) \
class gorgon_enumtraits_##type {\
public:\
    gorgon_enumtraits_##type() : mapping({__VA_ARGS__}) { }\
    \
    static const bool isupgradedenum=true;\
    \
    static const char *name() { return #type; }\
    \
    const std::multimap<type, std::string> mapping;\
};\
gorgon_enumtraits_##type gorgon__enum_tr_loc(const type &);

There is gorgon__enum_tr_loc function for non-upgraded types:
class gorgon__no_enum_trait {
public:
    static const bool isupgradedenum=false;
};


template<class T_>
gorgon__no_enum_trait gorgon__enum_tr_loc(const T_ &);

I am certain you can move from here to complete the system. SFINAE should be used for generic functions that will help you stream insert, extract, convert to string and enumerate. This system can be upgraded to use constexpr and string_view. You can access the code from here. Although the library itself is in GPL, you can use utility code like enum or string using MIT or BSD license.

You are massively underestimating what even basic reflection will be able to do… and can do, right now, in existing experimental implementations. A trivial reflection metafunction can do everything DefineEnumStrings does, with only a fraction of the code both at the call site and in the implementation, and much, much more. (Also, your library’s code is invalid; it is using illegal identifiers.)

@indi Sure, builtin reflection will mean no additional code. But, reflection should only be used as last resort, except in this case for type casting and looping through values, which both are possible in the full implementation. I am curious, what are the illegal identifiers? Here is one question and associated answers about abusing reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429962/when-do-you-use-reflection-patterns-anti-patterns

That StackOverflow discussion is about C# reflection, which is NOTHING like (proposed) C++ reflection. C++ reflection is static reflection… specifically to avoid all those problems with Java/C#-style reflection. C++ reflection will be zero-cost at run-time. “Reflection should be a last resort”… after the preprocessor?!?! Absolutely absurd. Frankly, I couldn’t even use your library in the next-gen codebases I work on, because preprocessor macros don’t work with modules. Between constexpr, modules, and reflection, the preprocessor will be pretty much obsolete. And good riddance.

As for the illegal identifiers: From lex.name p3.1: “Each identifier that contains a double underscore __ … is reserved to the implementation for any use.” The very first identifier I saw in your library: class gorgon__no_enum_trait.

We are not there yet. God knows when compilers will support reflection. I don't like to use preprocessor, but it reduces the work needs to be done in these cases. I think what we need is a namespaced, type checked C++ preprocessor that is used to generate code. You could replace that with static reflection in some cases, but I think preprocessor will still be easier to debug as you can easily obtain processed code to see the code that it produces.

2 compilers already support reflection, and have been tracking the reflection proposal. (Another chunk of the proposal was design-approved just 3 or 4 days ago.) As these have already shown, adding reflection to existing compilers is easy; compilers already do it internally, they just need to expose it to the programmer. (I read somewhere that someone managed to implement the 2021 reflection TS in GCC in ~1,500 lines.) “We’re not there yet”… technically true, but at this point we’re so close that it would be foolish to start a new macro-based library.

Also: “I think what we need is a namespaced, type checked C++ preprocessor that is used to generate code.”: “Hygienic macros” are part of the token sequence proposal. “… preprocessor will still be easier to debug as you can easily obtain processed code…”: That is already being considered. Again, you underestimating what is coming. The goal is that you will even be able to generate arbitrary additional output files from code while compiling. You should check out Herb Sutter’s 2024 CppCon keynote when it’s back up.

On a lark, I decided to try re-implementing your macro-based code as reflection-based code. I added error checking (something macros can’t really do), and made the main macro/metafunction significantly more powerful and flexible, yet the code turns out to be shorter. The code is very rough; I just slapped it together. But as you can see, reflection is real.

That is great! I am not against new systems, probably your code is what I will be doing as well, but in year 2030. Compiler support is too slow. We are still having problems with fmt on some dev machines. Also, I would need time to update the library. I still need to merge filesystem with std filesystem.
