Second Try at C++ 20 Generic Dictionary for enums and Strings
This is a follow up question to Abstract Generic Dictionary. Some of the code reviewed in this question was also reviewed in C++20 Performance Test Code Generator.
The new template class attempts to solve the design problems pointed out in the Abstract Generic Dictionary question.
The differences in the following code from the original questions:

The class is no longer abstract.
Errors in the data are now detected and reported.
A lot of template specialization was added.
There are now 4 constructors, 2 that throw exceptions and 2 that don't throw exceptions. A default constructor has been added that allows the data to be added at runtime. std::array is accepted for construction at runtime.
2 of the constructors accept lists of input, one accepts an initializer list, the other accepts a vector.
The user can enable exceptions in the runtime code during development.
The underlying data structures have been changed from std::vector to std::unordered_map().

The unit tests attempt to test all the paths through the code.
Example Error Messages:
testing AddVectorMultiIDMultiNames Limits Only Constructor - Duplicate IDs Duplicate Names in Vector
testing AddVectorMultiIDMultiNames.addAllDefinitions(testVecMultiNameMultiID)
In GenericDictionary::addAllDefinitions(): 
    missing enum value: 3
    duplicate enum values: 5 Name: New funct 2 - 5 Name: New funct 5
    missing enum value: 9
    duplicate enum values: 10 Name: New funct 9 - 10 Name: New funct 10
    
In GenericDictionary::addAllDefinitions(): Duplicate names found: 
    Name: New funct 1 Integer Value of ID: 1
    Name: New funct 2 Integer Value of ID: 2
    Name: New funct 5 Integer Value of ID: 4
    Name: New funct 2 Integer Value of ID: 5
    Name: New funct 5 Integer Value of ID: 5
    Name: New funct 6 Integer Value of ID: 6
    Name: New funct 1 Integer Value of ID: 11
    Name: New funct 2 Integer Value of ID: 12
    Name: New funct 6 Integer Value of ID: 16
    

Questions:

Do you think you would be able to maintain this code?
Is the code ready for use by others (RFUBO)?
Are the method names clear?
Do you think you can use this code in a project?
Is there too much template specialization?
Are there any C++ 20 concepts I could use to make the code shorter? The functions that error check for multiple enum usage, missing enums and multiple string usage come to mind for this question.

Development Environment:

Ubuntu 22.04
gcc-12 (this may limit c++ range features I have access to)

The Code to be Reviewed.
GitHub Repository
genericDictionary.h
#ifndef GENERICDICTIONARY_H_
#define GENERICDICTIONARY_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <concepts>
#include <exception>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

#ifdef GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST
#define GD_UNIT_TEST
#endif // GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST

/*
 * This class provides a basic conversion of enums or integers to strings. The
 * class can be used as is, or as a base for more complex object.
 * 
 * More complex objects than strings are also supported, however, overrides will
 * be necessary.
 * 
 * This class makes an attempt to find any missing definitions during construction.
 * 
 * Enums or integers should have an illegal value as 0. If not, then override the
 * getIds method.
 * 
 * The code has been modified based on the Code Reviews
 * https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/293782/generic-c-class-to-associate-enum-values-with-strings-for-translation
 * and
 * https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/293933/c20-performance-test-code-generator
 * Changes since the reviews
 * - Multiple constructors and a destructor have been added.
 * - The lists are checked for missing definitions and duplicate definitions
 * - The class is no longer abstract
 * - dicID became dictID and dicName became dictName
 * - The struct used by the constructor now has a template GenricDictionaryDataPair.
 * - The unit test code has been added to this file to ease maintenance.
 * - The code for all the methods and constructors have been moved into template specializations.
 * - There is a constructor that does not need to be wrapped in a try catch block.
 * 
 */

/******************************************************************************
 * Data structures and class Declarations
 *****************************************************************************/
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
struct GenricDictionaryDataPair
{
    dictID id;
    dictName names;
};

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
class GenericDictionary
{
public:
    using DictType = GenricDictionaryDataPair<dictID, dictName>;

// Both the MinValue and MaxValue should be invalid values
// Example
// GenericDictionary(enum::NO_VALUE, enum::LAST_VALUE)

    GenericDictionary()
    : MinimumValue{0},
      MaximumValue{0}
    {};

// Safe constructor that will not throw exceptions, but the search table is
// not initialized.
    GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue)
    : MinimumValue{MinValue},
      MaximumValue{MaxValue}
      {};
// The following constructors will throw exceptions if there are problems in the
// list of definitions.
    GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions);
    GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::vector<DictType> definitions);
    virtual ~GenericDictionary() = default;

    virtual dictID getIds(dictName itemName);
    virtual dictName getNames(dictID id);
    bool addAllDefinitions(std::ranges::input_range auto&& definitions);
    bool addAllDefinitions(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::ranges::input_range auto&& definitions);
    bool addAllDefinitions(std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions);
    bool addAllDefinitions(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions);
    void enableExceptions(bool exceptionsEnabled) { throwException = exceptionsEnabled; };

#ifdef GD_UNIT_TEST
    std::vector<DictType> getUserInput() const noexcept { return userInputList; }
    bool selfUnitTest();
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
    void debugDumpData() const noexcept;
    void debugDumpUserList() noexcept { debugDumpList(userInputList); };
    void debugDumpList(std::vector<DictType> candidate) noexcept;
#endif // DEBUG

protected:
    [[nodiscard]] bool commonInternalListBuilder(std::string funcName) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool alreadyDefined(DictType candidate) noexcept { return hasID(candidate.id) || hasName(candidate.names); };
    [[nodiscard]] bool missingIDSizeTest(std::string funcName) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool reportDuplicateNameErrors(std::string funcName) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool hasID(dictID id) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool hasName(dictName name) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool limitsNotSet(std::string funcName, std::string searchValue) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool sanityCheck(std::string funcName, std::string searchValue) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool searchTableNotInitialized(std::string funcName, std::string searchValue) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool sortAndTestIds(std::string& emsg) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool testForIDNoneLinearDefinitions(std::string funcName) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool addDefinition(DictType newDef) noexcept;

/*
 * Don't change the order of the following 2 member variables since they
 * are set in contructors and the order is important.
 */
    dictID MinimumValue;
    dictID MaximumValue;

    std::unordered_map<dictID, dictName> idSearchTable;
    std::unordered_map<dictName, dictID> nameSearchTable;
    std::vector<DictType> userInputList;
    bool throwException = false;
};

/******************************************************************************
 * Public interface specializations.
 *****************************************************************************/
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions)
: MinimumValue{MinValue},
MaximumValue{MaxValue}
{
    for (auto const& newDef : definitions)
    {
        userInputList.push_back(newDef);
    }

    if (!commonInternalListBuilder("Constructor"))
    {
        std::logic_error constructorError("GenericDictionary::GenericDictionary(std::initializer_list): Search List Initialization");
        throw constructorError;
    }
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::vector<DictType> definitions)
: MinimumValue{MinValue},
MaximumValue{MaxValue},
userInputList{definitions}
{
    if (!commonInternalListBuilder("Constructor"))
    {
        std::logic_error constructorError("GenericDictionary::GenericDictionary(std::vector): Search List Initialization Error");
        throw constructorError;
    }
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
dictID GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::getIds(dictName itemName)
{
    if (sanityCheck("getIds", "name value"))
    {
        auto definition = nameSearchTable.find(itemName);
        if (definition != nameSearchTable.end())
        {
            return definition->second;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (throwException)
        {
            std::logic_error constructionError("GenericDictionary::addAllDefinitions(): Errors Occured.");
            throw constructionError;
        }

    }

    return static_cast<dictID>(MinimumValue);
};

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
dictName GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::getNames(dictID id)
{
    if (sanityCheck("getNames", "enum value") && (MinimumValue < id && id < MaximumValue))
    {
        auto definition = idSearchTable.find(id);
        if (definition != idSearchTable.end())
        {
            return definition->second;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (throwException)
        {
            std::logic_error constructionError("GenericDictionary::addAllDefinitions(): Errors Occured.");
            throw constructionError;
        }

    }

    dictName nameNotFound;
    return nameNotFound;
}

/*
 * This method is used when a default constructor has been used to create the object.
 */
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::addAllDefinitions(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::ranges::input_range auto&& definitions)
{
    MinimumValue = MinValue;
    MaximumValue = MaxValue;
    return addAllDefinitions(definitions);
}

/*
 * All the other addAllDefinitions() functions reference this function.
 */
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::addAllDefinitions(std::ranges::input_range auto&& definitions)
{
    bool noErrors = true;

    if (limitsNotSet("addAllDefinitions",""))
    {
        return false;
    }

// There is no guarantee that definitions are a vector so translate
    for (auto const& newDef : definitions)
    {
        userInputList.push_back(newDef);
    }

    if (noErrors)
    {
        noErrors = commonInternalListBuilder("addAllDefinitions()");
        if (throwException)
        {
            std::logic_error constructionError("GenericDictionary::addAllDefinitions(): Errors Occured.");
            throw constructionError;
        }
    }

    return noErrors;
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::addAllDefinitions(std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions)
{
    std::vector<DictType> tmpMap;

    for (auto const& newDef : definitions)
    {
        tmpMap.push_back(newDef);
    }

    return addAllDefinitions(tmpMap);
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::addAllDefinitions(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions)
{
    std::vector<DictType> tmpMap;

    for (auto const& newDef : definitions)
    {
        tmpMap.push_back(newDef);
    }

    return addAllDefinitions(MinValue, MaxValue, tmpMap);
}

#ifdef DEBUG
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
void GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::debugDumpList(std::vector<DictType> toDump) noexcept
{
    for (auto searchItem: toDump)
    {
        std::cerr << "\t\tID int value " << static_cast<std::size_t>(searchItem.id) 
            << " Name value " << searchItem.names << "\n";
    }
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
void GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::debugDumpData() const noexcept
{
    std::cerr << "\n\nGenericDictionary::Debug Dump Data\n";
    std::cerr << "\tMinimumValue: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(MinimumValue) << "\n";
    std::cerr << "\tMaximumValue: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(MaximumValue) << "\n";
    std::cerr << "ID Search Table:\n\t{\n";
    for (auto searchItem: idSearchTable)
    {
        std::cerr << "\t\tID int value " << static_cast<std::size_t>(searchItem.first) 
            << " Name value " << searchItem.second << "\n";
    }
    std::cerr << "\t}\n";
    std::cerr << "Name Search Table:\n\t{\n";
    for (auto searchItem: nameSearchTable)
    {
        std::cerr << "\t\tID int value " << static_cast<std::size_t>(searchItem.second) 
            << " Name value " << searchItem.first << "\n";
    }
    std::cerr << "\t}\n";
}
#endif // DEBUG

/******************************************************************************
 * Protected/Private methods
 *****************************************************************************/

template<typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::commonInternalListBuilder(std::string funcName) noexcept
{
    bool hasErrors = false;   
    if (missingIDSizeTest(funcName))
    {
        hasErrors = true;
    }

    if (!testForIDNoneLinearDefinitions(funcName))
    {
        hasErrors = true;
    }

    if (reportDuplicateNameErrors(funcName))
    {
        hasErrors = true;
    }

    if (hasErrors)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Errors have been found, there is no need to add the definitions to the maps.
    for (auto newDef: userInputList)
    {
        if (!addDefinition(newDef))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

template<typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::sanityCheck(std::string funcName, std::string searchValue) noexcept
{
    if (limitsNotSet(funcName, searchValue))
    {
        return false;
    }
// if the limits aren't set there is no need to check searchtable initialization.
    if (searchTableNotInitialized(funcName, searchValue))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

template<typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::limitsNotSet(std::string funcName, std::string searchValue) noexcept
{
    if (!(static_cast<std::size_t>(MaximumValue) > static_cast<std::size_t>(MinimumValue)))
    {
        std::string emsg("In GenericDictionary::" + funcName + " (" + searchValue +"): ");
        emsg += "The minimum and maximum enum values have not been set.";
        std::cerr << emsg << "\n";
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

template<typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::searchTableNotInitialized(std::string funcName, std::string searchValue) noexcept
{
    if (idSearchTable.size() == 0 || nameSearchTable.size() == 0)
    {
        std::string emsg("In GenericDictionary::" + funcName + " (" + searchValue +"): ");
        emsg += "searchTable has not been initialized.";
        std::cerr << emsg << "\n";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*
 * Sorts the user input. After sorting the input performs various tests
 * on the validity of the input, finding duplicate IDs or missing IDs. The
 * input must be sorted before the the error checking can be performed.
 */
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::sortAndTestIds(std::string& emsg) noexcept
{
    std::sort(userInputList.begin(), userInputList.end(),
        [](DictType defIter1, DictType defIter2) {return  defIter1.id < defIter2.id;});

    bool noErrors = true;

    for (auto defIter2 = userInputList.begin() + 1; defIter2 < userInputList.end(); defIter2++ )
    {
        auto defIter1 = defIter2 - 1;
        std::size_t id1 = static_cast<std::size_t>(defIter1->id);
        std::size_t id2 = static_cast<std::size_t>(defIter2->id);
        if (id1 != (id2 - 1))
        {
            if (id1 == id2)
            {
                emsg += "duplicate enum values: " + std::to_string(id1) + " Name: " + defIter1->names + " - " + std::to_string(id2) +
                    " Name: " + defIter2->names + "\n\t";
            }
            else
            {
                emsg += "missing enum value: " + std::to_string((id2 - 1)) + "\n\t";
            }
            noErrors = false;
        }
    }

    return noErrors;
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::missingIDSizeTest(std::string funcName) noexcept
{
    std::size_t expectedSize = static_cast<std::size_t>(MaximumValue);
    expectedSize -= 1;
    if (userInputList.size() != expectedSize)
    {
        std::string emsg("In GenericDictionary::" + funcName + " missing definition values");
        emsg += " expected size " + std::to_string(expectedSize) + " actual size " + std::to_string(userInputList.size());
        std::cerr << emsg << "\n";
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::hasID(dictID id) noexcept
{
    auto found = idSearchTable.find(id);
    return (found != idSearchTable.end());
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::hasName(dictName name) noexcept
{
    auto found = nameSearchTable.find(name);
    return (found != nameSearchTable.end());
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::reportDuplicateNameErrors(std::string funcName) noexcept
{
    std::vector<DictType> duplicates;
    // Find all duplicate names, store the name and the ID to generate an
    // error message after all duplicates are found.
    for (auto defintion: userInputList)
    {
        std::size_t countNames = std::ranges::count(userInputList, defintion.names, &DictType::names);
        if (countNames > 1) 
        {
            duplicates.push_back(defintion);
        }
    }

    if (duplicates.size() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::string emsg("In GenericDictionary::" + funcName + ": Duplicate names found: \n\t");
    for (auto duplicate: duplicates)
    {
        emsg += "Name: " + duplicate.names + " Integer Value of ID: " +
            std::to_string(static_cast<std::size_t>(duplicate.id)) + "\n\t";
    }

    std::cerr << emsg << "\n";

    return true;
}

/*
 * Find and report any missing or duplicated enums
 */
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::testForIDNoneLinearDefinitions(
    std::string funcName
    ) noexcept
{
    bool noErrors = true; 
    std::string emsg("In GenericDictionary::" + funcName + ": \n\t");

    noErrors = sortAndTestIds(emsg);
    if (!noErrors)
    {
        std::cerr << emsg << "\n";
    }


    return noErrors;
}

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
[[nodiscard]] bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::addDefinition(DictType newDef) noexcept
{
    if (!alreadyDefined(newDef))
    {
        idSearchTable.insert({newDef.id, newDef.names});
        nameSearchTable.insert({newDef.names, newDef.id});
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/******************************************************************************
 * Unit testing and performance testing of the GenericDictinary class are
 * here to ease the maintenance of the testing and of the class. By default
 * if we are perfomance testing we are also unit testing.
 ******************************************************************************/

#ifdef GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST
#include "UtilityTimer.h"
#endif // GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST

#ifdef GD_UNIT_TEST
#include <iostream>

template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
bool GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::selfUnitTest()
{

    return true;
}

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testIdToName(
    GenericDictionary<enumDictType, std::string>& underTest,
    enumDictType testID,
    std::string expectedOutput,
    std::string errorMessage
)
{
    std::string testGetName = underTest.getNames(testID);
    if (testGetName.compare(expectedOutput) != 0)
    {
        std::cerr
            << "\t" << errorMessage << " Input Value " <<
            static_cast<std::size_t>(testID)
            << " Expected Output " << expectedOutput << " " 
            << " Actual Ouput " << testGetName << "\n";
            ;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testNameToID(
    GenericDictionary<enumDictType, std::string>& underTest,
    std::string testName,
    enumDictType expectedOutput,
    std::string errorMessage
    )
{
    enumDictType testGetID = underTest.getIds(testName);
    if (testGetID != expectedOutput)
    {
        std::cerr <<
            "\t " << errorMessage << " get ID from Name FAILED: "
            << "Input Name: " << testName
            << " Expected Output: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(expectedOutput)
            << " Actual Output: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(testGetID)
            << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

template <typename  enumDictType> using TestPairs = GenricDictionaryDataPair<enumDictType, std::string>;

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testIDtoNameLoop(
    GenericDictionary <enumDictType, std::string>& underTest,
    std::vector<GenricDictionaryDataPair<enumDictType, std::string>>& TestData,
    std::string errorMessage
)
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;

    for (auto test: TestData)
    {
        enumDictType testId = test.id;
        std::string expectedOutPut = test.names;
        std::string testGetName = underTest.getNames(testId);
        if (testGetName.compare(expectedOutPut) != 0)
        {
            std::cerr
                << "\t" << errorMessage << " Input Value " <<
                static_cast<std::size_t>(testId)
                << " Expected Output " << expectedOutPut << " " 
                << " Actual Ouput " << testGetName << "\n";
                ;
            allTestsPassed = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testNametoIDLoop(
    GenericDictionary <enumDictType, std::string>& underTest,
    std::vector<GenricDictionaryDataPair<enumDictType, std::string>>& TestData,
    std::string errorMessage
)
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;

    for (auto test: TestData)
    {
        std::string testName = test.names;
        enumDictType expectedOutput = test.id;
        enumDictType testGetID = underTest.getIds(testName);
        if (testGetID != expectedOutput)
        {
            std::cerr <<
                "\t " << errorMessage << " get ID from Name FAILED: "
                << "Input Name: " << testName
                << " Expected Output: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(expectedOutput)
                << " Actual Output: " << static_cast<std::size_t>(testGetID)
                << "\n";
            allTestsPassed = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

#ifdef GD_PERFORMANCE_TEST
/*
 * This function tests the performance of the searches for selected, the first
 * the last and 3 middle values.
 */
template <typename enumDictType>
static bool testMinMaxMiddleValues(
    GenericDictionary <enumDictType, std::string>& underTest,
    std::vector<TestPairs<enumDictType>>& testData,
    std::string testName
)
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;
    UtilityTimer testTimer;

    std::vector<std::size_t> indexes;
    indexes.push_back(static_cast<std::size_t>(testData.size() - 1));
    if (testData.size() > 10)
    {
        indexes.push_back(static_cast<std::size_t>((testData.size() * 0.75) - 1));
        indexes.push_back(static_cast<std::size_t>((testData.size() * 0.5) - 1));
        indexes.push_back(static_cast<std::size_t>((testData.size() * 0.25) -1));
    }
    indexes.push_back(0);

    for (auto tIndex: indexes)
    {
        auto tDp = testData[tIndex];
        std::string testReport = "Performance Test find string from [" + std::to_string(tIndex) + "] ID " + testName + " ";
        testTimer.startTimer();
        allTestsPassed = testIdToName<enumDictType>(underTest, tDp.id, tDp.names, testName + " testIDToName()");
        testTimer.stopTimerAndReport(testReport);
        if (!allTestsPassed)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (auto tIndex: indexes)
    {
        auto tDp = testData[tIndex];
        std::string testReport = "Performance Test find ID from [" + std::to_string(tIndex) + "] Name " + testName + " ";
        testTimer.startTimer();
        allTestsPassed = testNameToID<enumDictType>(underTest, tDp.names, tDp.id, testName + " testNameToID()");
        testTimer.stopTimerAndReport(testReport);

        if (!allTestsPassed)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

template <typename enumDictType>
static bool performanceExecution(
    GenericDictionary <enumDictType, std::string>& underTest,
    std::vector<TestPairs<enumDictType>>& testData,
    std::string testName
)
{
    bool allTestsPassed = true;
    UtilityTimer testTimer;

    testMinMaxMiddleValues<enumDictType>(underTest, testData, testName);
    if (!allTestsPassed)
    {
        return false;
    }

    testTimer.startTimer();
    testIDtoNameLoop<enumDictType>(underTest, testData, testName + " testIDtoNameLoop()");
    testTimer.stopTimerAndReport("Performance Loop Test find string from ID " + testName + " ");
    if (!allTestsPassed)
    {
        return false;
    }

    testTimer.startTimer();
    testNametoIDLoop<enumDictType>(underTest, testData, testName + " testNametoIDLoop()");
    testTimer.stopTimerAndReport("Performance Loop Test find ID from Name " + testName + " ");
    if (!allTestsPassed)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}
#endif

#endif // GD_UNIT_TEST

#endif // GENERICDICTIONARY_H_



At first glance, the first thing that stands out to me is that you (sensibly) only do any I/O if DEBUG is defined. So perhaps you want to make the include of <iostream> conditional as well.

@Chris What about error messages to std::cerr?

I missed that some of them occur outside of that conditional. This doesn't seem like good design. Functions like GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::limitsNotSet should be throwing exceptions and letting the calling code catch and handle them.

@Chris The boolean that that function returns is checked, if the user enabled exceptions, then an exception is thrown.

While there are 2 very extensive answers I am going to wait another 2 days before accepting an answer to allow others to participate. The 2 answers posted so far are both very educational.

Naming
The code starts with a typo: GenricDictionaryDataPair. Even if fixed, generic names are often bad, and this one even has "generic" in its name. Usually I recommed creating structs instead of using std::pair and std::tuple, but if there is ever a place to just use std::pair, this is it: it's just a generic key/value pair, and it's already used by std::map and friends for the same purpose, so programmers should already be familiar with its use in this context.
names in GenricDictionaryDataPair sounds like it can contain multiple names, but it's just a single one, so it should be name.
GenericDictionary: this is not a generic dictionary, but one specifically made for mapping enum identifiers to names. Maybe call it EnumDictionary?
addAllDefinitions(): the word All doesn't mean anything here. Sure it can add multiple definitions in one go, but it doesn't mean you add all definitions using a single call. addDefinitions() would be better, but considering that you wouldn't add anything else besides definitions, and the purpose of the class is to hold definitions, I'd just write add(). But then why not copy the standard library's nomenclature and name it insert() and/or perhaps insert_range()?
getIds() and getNames(): these functions just return one identifier or one name, so they shouldn't be plural.
Restrict the allowed types
You did not use concepts to restrict the allowed types of dictID and dictName, but it's clear from the code that you cannot use any type you want. dictID must be a valid enum type, or at least something that can be used as the underlying type for an enum.
dictName has to be hashable, printable and that you can add it to other strings. You are basically assuming it's a std::string. Maybe just make this explicit?
The lookup functions are weird
Apart from the plural names, why are getIds() and getNames() virtual? Even worse though, if you specify an incorrect name, getIds() will just return MinimumValue, which the caller cannot distinguish from an error. getNames() will return an empty name for an enum value that doesn't have a defined name, which is slightly better, but it's very likely someone will forget to handle this case.
enableExceptions() is unreliable
This function is a bad idea. Now there is some state which can be changed anywhere in the code, making it hard to reason about whether exceptions are really enabled or not. Also, when exceptions are disabled, errors are just ignored, and something is returned that is hard for the caller to distinguish from a valid value.
I recommend you use a single way to return errors. Either that can be by throwing exceptions, or by returning a std::optional or if you can use C++23, std::expected.
Accept any kind of container in the constructor
You have a constructor that takes a std::vector<DictType>, but you don't allow any other container types. You also pass it by value, which can be inefficient. Just make it take a std::ranges::input_range auto&& instead, just like you do in one of the addAllDefinitions() overloads.
Only allow the constructor to add definitions
I think the addAllDefinitions() functions are a bad idea. It would be best if the GenericDictionary was completely initialized and valid just by constructing it. The constructor can then immediately do a sanity check and throw an exception if invalid data was passed. This then also avoids having to do sanity checks in all the other functions.

I have created a chat room specifically for this question and related questions and for the answers to those questions. I'd like you to join the discussion. I find your answers quite educational.

Design review
Before I begin, I just want to make sure I’m understanding what the goal of the code is. If I’m understanding correctly, this is a bidirectional map (bimap) between the values of an enumeration, and “something else” (most likely strings). If that’s not correct, then please just ignore the rest of the review.
This is an extremely expensive system
Bi-mapping enumerations with strings is very useful, and very widely used. You’re even going one step further, and allowing a bi-mapping between an enumeration and anything. That’s hella useful.
But do keep in mind that what you’ve made is extremely heavy weight. For just mapping enumerations to strings, it’s probably way, way too much. Normally when an enumeration is mapped to strings, it is done with flat arrays stored directly in the program’s data segment. That makes the memory cost zero, at the cost of linear search times when doing the look-ups. But that cost is effectively zero, too, in practice. Consider that doing enumeration-to-string is pretty much always done when formatting a string for output or display. In that case, the cost of the output probably dwarfs any mapping costs by at least an order of magnitude, if not more. And when going the other way, the only times that ever happens is during input and parsing. Again, the relative cost of the actual mapping there is probably not even measurable.
I haven’t measured it, but I’d bet if you were to do:
enum class foo
{
    value_1,
    value_2,
    // ...
};

constexpr auto foo_strings = std::to_array<std::pair<foo, std::string_view>({
    {value_1, "string for value 1"},
    {value_2, "string for value 2"},
    // ...
});

constexpr auto to_string(foo v)
{
    if (auto i = std::ranges::find(foo_strings, v, &std::pair<foo, std::string_view>::first); i != foo_strings.end())
        return i->second;
    // handle error...
}

… then for any reasonably-sized number of enumerators, to_string(foo::value_x) would be many, many times faster than dict.getNames(foo:value_x). The number of enumerators you’d need to make unordered_set’s node-based binary search faster than a flat linear search is probably on the order of tens of thousands, if not hundreds of thousands or even millions of enumerators.
It probably won’t take quite so many enumerators to make the reverse mapping from strings faster with a hash map. But still, is that really something that needs to be fast? In what use case would you be decoding from strings to enumeration values in a hot loop?
Using this kind of structure for enumeration to string bi-mappings would make sense if:

you have an enumeration with many thousands of enumerators, and you need to convert enumeration values to strings frequently (and not just, for example, when an error happens and you want to log it); or
you are parsing many thousands of enumeration values and are compute-bound rather than I/O bound.

But those aren’t exactly common circumstances.
All that being said, while using a structure like this for simple enumeration to string conversions (or vice versa) probably isn’t worth it, that may not be true for other kinds of enumeration to “something” mappings. That could be very useful in the general case. You’d still need to consider whether bi-directional mapping is worth it, but there are certainly a lot of situations where it could be.
To be clear, I’m not saying this code is a bad idea. I’m saying that the use case you’ve mentioned—string mapping—is probably not a good use case for something like this. But something like this could definitely be useful for mapping enumeration value keys to other stuff, if bi-directional mapping is necessary, and especially if we’re talking large enumerations or large numbers of mapped values.
“Forcing” the shape of an enumeration is unwise
In order to work with this type, an enumeration has to have a few properties:

it has to have consecutive enumerators
there must be an underlying value below the lowest valid enumerator
there must be an underlying value above the highest valid enumerator
an enumerator must be created for the value just below the lowest valid enumerator; and
an enumerator must be created for the value just above the highest valid enumerator.

All of these constrains exist for two reasons:

so you can have an “invalid” value to return in the case of errors; and
so you can verify that no enumerators are not mapped to strings.

Now, the first reason is undermined by the existence of std::expected and std::optional, which exist explicitly so that you don’t need an “invalid” value in order to signal the lack of a value. Instead of:
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
dictID GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::getIds(dictName itemName)
{
    if (sanityCheck("getIds", "name value"))
    {
        auto definition = nameSearchTable.find(itemName);
        if (definition != nameSearchTable.end())
        {
            return definition->second;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (throwException)
        {
            std::logic_error constructionError("GenericDictionary::addAllDefinitions(): Errors Occured.");
            throw constructionError;
        }

    }

    return static_cast<dictID>(MinimumValue);
};

// Usage:
auto id = dict.getIds(whatever); // may or may not throw on error
if (id != enumeration::invalid_value)
    use(id);
else
    // error

… you can do:
enum class dictionary_errc
{
    id_not_found,
    value_not_found
};

template<typename Id, typename Name>
auto GenericDictionary<Id, Name>::getIds(dictName const& itemName) const
    -> std::expected<Id, dictionary_errc>
{
    if (sanityCheck("getIds", "name value"))
    {
        auto definition = nameSearchTable.find(itemName);
        if (definition != nameSearchTable.end())
        {
            return definition->second;
        }
    }

    // No need to remember if the user wants exceptions; if they do they
    // will get one automatically, and if they don’t they will be
    // checking anyway.
    //
    // Technically we could also return an unexpected dictionary_errc
    // from the sanity check, so if the sanity check fails, we could
    // return information about exactly why. But the sanity check is a
    // problem on its own that we'll get to later.

    return std::unexpected{dictionary_errc::name_not_found};
};

// Usage:
auto id = dict.getIds(whatever); // will never throw
if (id)
    use(*id);
else
    // error

// Or, if you don't mind an exception:
use(dict.getIds(whatever).value());


// Or using monadic ops:
dict.getIds(whatever)
    .and_then(use)
    .or_else(/* error */)
;

But there is a more insidious problem with the idea of “invalid values” for an enumeration. To put it simply: properly designed types should not have an invalid value.
Let’s consider an enumeration for a valve control in a complex system. There are only two possible states for the valve: “open” or “closed”. Everywhere in the entire program, the logic is simple: if you need the valve to be open, you do if (valve.state != valve_state::open) valve.open();… if you need it to be closed, you do if (valve.state != valve_state::closed) valve.close();. Simple.
Now you introduce valve_state::invalid… or valve_state::min_value, or anything else that is not “open” or “closed”. Now everywhere… in the entire program… every time you just want to do one of those simple checks, you have to introduce complex logic and error handling. If you miss even one place, you may have a catastrophic bug. And the complexity of every single function that uses valves has now exploded: where before you could write complex logic very simply (“if valves 1 through 5 are open, and valve 6 is closed, then open valves 7 through 9”), now everything has to be checked, obfuscating the important operational logic.
So forcing people to break perfectly good enumerations by adding invalid state is a terrible idea. It’s not even necessary if all you want to do is signal “nothing to return” or “not found”; for that you could use std::expected or std::optional; whichever makes sense in context. (Use std::expected when you mean to say “this function should return a value, and if it could not, that was because something was wrong”; use std::optional when you mean “this function should return a value, but if there was no value to return, that’s not an error”. In the fairly rare case where you have “this function should return a value, but there can sometimes be no value and that’s fine, however there may still be an actual error when trying to get the optional value”, you probably want expected<optional<T>, /*...*/>).
But what about the other reason you need these invalid values: to verify that all enumerators have been assigned strings?
Well, for that, I would say that goal itself is misguided.
Let’s take a step back, and consider what a user might actually need. We’ll assume they need a bi-mapping between a set of enumeration values and strings because… well, I mean, that’s the point, right?
But… do they need… ALL… enumerators mapped to strings?
You assume they do. They might not. They might want strings for most enumerators, but some could just use a default or fallback string:
dict.getNames(id)
    .and_then([](auto&& s) { std::print("{}", s); })
    .or_else([](auto&&) { std::print("meh"); })
;

I’ll even give an example: suppose you have an enumeration for HTTP status codes mapped to error strings. Status codes beginning with 1, 2, or 3 are not errors (though they may require further action by the client), but status codes beginning with 4 or 5 are. When the UA detects an error, it could pop up a box announcing it. For that, it would need a mapping of human-readable descriptions of the type of error, but it would be pointless and wasteful to map the non-error status codes.
Let’s go even further, and say, okay, maybe they don’t need every enumerator mapped to a string, but it would still be an error for there to be duplicates.
Except… would it?
Let’s imagine you’re making an enumeration to represent CSS3 named colours. For the most part this would be straight forward: colour::darkgoldenrod would map to "darkgoldenrod", and vice versa. However… what about grey? Or… is it “gray”?
Turns out it’s both colour::grey and colour::gray are the same colour in CSS. And there are other synonyms, like colour::cyan and colour::aqua.
Okay, you could argue this isn’t a problem because colour::cyan would be real and colour::aqua would just be set as = cyan, so it’s not two enumerators, it’s just one, and it will always map to the string "cyan". Sure, okay, I won’t argue but… what about the other way? colour::cyan and colour::aqua may be the same value, but "cyan" and "aqua" can’t be the same string. And you want to be able to parse the string and get the colour code, so parsing either "cyan" or "aqua" should return colour::cyan. So you need duplicate enumerators in this case.
(And there are many cases where you would need duplicate strings, where multiple enumerators that maybe once had different meanings have been coalesced into one.)
So I ask: Why are you preventing the user from either using duplicates or skipping enumerators? How is that helping the user?
I know what the thinking process was that got you to this point. You are fixated on the case of having string values for enumerators, where you need string values for every enumerator, and where having duplicates just makes no sense. Because that is the use case you are focused on, it seems to make sense that you would want to help the user by making sure they do get all the enumerators covered.
But as I said, that is misguided.
For starters, that is just a single, particular use case. (And, frankly, one that is better served by a constant mapping in the data section. But put that aside for the moment.) By designing the whole thing around that single, particular use case, you prevent multitudes of other use cases.
And even for that one particular use case, the thinking is misguided. Let’s say that use case is exactly what I want: I want a mapping of strings to enumerators, and I want 100% coverage, and no duplicates. For whatever reason, this is important to me.
Okay, but if that’s the case, if it really is important to me that I get 100% coverage and no duplicates… well, then… I have to test that.
Any property of my code that is important to me must be tested. That’s just a truism. I would be a shitty programmer if I needed something to be true in my code, and I just… shrugged and assumed it will all work out.
So I need to write the tests to confirm that every enumerator is covered, that the strings are what I expect them to be, and that the mapping is bijective: there are no duplicates on either side of the mapping. Regardless of anything happening in your class, I need to write those tests.
See what I’m getting at? All the work your class is doing to verify and enforce 100% coverage and a bijective mapping—which incidentally prevents many other useful use cases—is totally irrelevant. If that’s what I actually want, I have to test for it anyway. I don’t need your class’s help for any of that: if I miss an enumerator or introduce a duplicate, my tests will catch it. (Or if they don’t then my tests are broken, but that’s a me problem.)
So if you completely remove all that functionality and the associated requirements, not only do you spare yourself a lot of work, and massively simplify the class, you actually make it more useful, because now it can handle use cases without contiguous enumerator values, without “invalid” values, without needing all enumerators to be accounted for, and you allow duplicates for cases where that makes sense. Sometimes, quite often, less is more.
Two hash maps is probably not the best design
Let’s strip the type down to its core. Fundamentally, the class is a pair of maps: one for each mapping direction:
template<typename Enum, typename Value>
class GenericDictionary
{
    std::unordered_map<Enum, Value> enum_to_val;
    std::unordered_map<Value, Enum> val_to_enum;
};

There are two main areas of concern for me with this design.
The first is efficiency. Hash mapping values to enumerators makes sense in the general case, because for most types, a hash map will be more efficient than a non-hashed map. But hash mapping enumerators to anything is a waste of time, because the hash of any enumerator will be… the enumerator. Using a hash map with an enumerator key means you’re paying for all the massive complexity and overhead of the hash functionality—including keeping track of the buckets and whatnot—when you will never need any of it, because there can be no such thing a hash collision. A standard non-hash map would probably be more efficient. But even that, you could do much, much better. Put a pin in that, we’ll get back to it.
My second, and much more important, concern has to do with identity and data duplication.
So, having duplicates of strings is wasteful, but not otherwise harmful. But some types cannot be meaningfully duplicated. “Copying” them may produce an observably different “thing”. Such types might even be move-only (and probably usually are).
Here’s the problem. Let’s say I’m mapping enumerators stoplight::red, stoplight::green, and stoplight::yellow to the strings “"red"”, “"green"”, and “"yellow"” respectively.
Obviously the enumerator-to-value mapping has the following:
{stoplight::red,    "red"},
{stoplight::green,  "green"},
{stoplight::yellow, "yellow"}

… in whatever order. No problems here.
But now the value-to-enumerator mapping has:
{"red",    stoplight::red},
{"green",  stoplight::green},
{"yellow", stoplight::yellow}

… but here is the critical point: those are not the same values as in the previous map. They are copies. The string “yellow” in the first map is not the same string “yellow” that is in the second map. Their internal data pointers point to different sets of characters. (Yanno, ignoring SSO.)
Which means that if you change the string in the first map, it doesn’t change in the second map. That can’t occur in your current code, nor should it ever be able to if the class is well-written. I’m not so much worried about whether it could happen as I am about the fact that it could.
For the enumerators, this is a moot point, because you can’t “modify” an enumerator. It is what it is. You could replace it, but that would require visibly assigning a new value. Strings (and many other types) can be modified without replacement. It’s hard to see that because a const string can’t be modified… but a const std::span of a non-const type could. Other types with shallow const semantics could too. So even in a const member function of the dictionary, values could be modified, and the two maps could get out of sync.
Let me suggest a different implementation.
Instead of two maps, you could have a single hash mapping of values to enumerators, and then a vector of pairs of enumerators and pointers to the values in the hash map.
Keeping pointers to the values in a std::unordered_map is pretty safe: they are very hard to invalidate. Pretty much the only way to do it is to actually delete the element (directly or indirectly, such as by .clear() or the destructor). And while you are technically duplicating the enumerators… they’re ints (basically), so, meh.
So here’s what you do:

Copy data from an input range or whatever into the hash map.
Transform the hash map data into a vector of pairs of enumerators and pointers to the values. They would have to be const pointers because that’s how unordered_map keeps its keys.
Sort the vector by enumerator.

Now when you do a lookup of a value, you do a hash map lookup, which is about as fast as it can get. When you do a lookup of an enumerator, you do a binary search on the vector… because it is sorted… which again is just about as fast it can possibly get. (Although, realistically, for something like this a linear search will probably be just about as fast, and possibly even faster, due to more predictable cache pre-fetching. Frankly, I’d just do the linear search unless there are tens or hundreds of thousands of elements in the vector.)
I’m hand-waving over a tiny bit of complexity about dealing with duplicates, but that’s about it.
This setup would not only prevent the duplication/identity problem, it would probably be significantly more efficient. I’d be curious to see benchmarking results for it.
Questions
Do you think you would be able to maintain this code?
The class itself? Yes, definitely. The testing stuff, not so much.
Is the code ready for use by others (RFUBO)?
I would say so, yes.
Are the method names clear?
Perhaps even overly clear.
For example, addAllDefinitions… could probably just be add. What else would you be adding to a dictionary, if not dictionary definitions?
Do you think you can use this code in a project?
Probably not, for a couple of reasons:

As I mentioned above, the fact that this requires creating invalid states for an enumeration is a pretty hard deal-breaker for me. If my enumeration represents \$N\$ valid states, then it must have \$N\$ enumerators, no more, no less. If you lighten up the restrictions—don’t require min/max values—then that problem goes away.
I realize this isn’t an issue for most people, but for me, the lack of allocator support is another deal-breaker, for quite a few of my projects, though not all. In many cases, I need to be able to put allocations in a specific area, or just as often, use stack-based allocation. Adding allocator support wouldn’t be too hard, and that would make this objection go away too.
As I mentioned, given that none of my enumerations have hundreds of enumerators, and that I can define everything in the data segment thus requiring no allocations, this type offers me no benefits. However, for mapping enumerations to stuff not so easily put in the data segment, or for mappings defined at run-time… yes, I can see uses for this.

So I wouldn’t say I would never use this, especially if point 1 is solved.
Is there too much template specialization?
Unless I’m missing something, I don’t see any template specialization. I think you are confused about terminology.
Specializing a template means replacing its generic parameters with specific (or partially specific) ones: specific→specialized. The generic parameters in your template are dictID and dictName. A specialization would mean replacing one or both of those with a concrete type (or, in the case of partial specializtion, a more concrete type, though not necessarily completely concrete).
This is not a specialization:
/******************************************************************************
 * Public interface specializations.
 *****************************************************************************/
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>::GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions)

That is just a member function definition (as opposed to just a declaration). It just happens to be outside of the class, so you need the template <typename dictID, typename dictName> GenericDictionary<dictID, dictName>:: part to clarify that it is part of the class.
If it were a specialization, it would look like this:
template<>
GenericDictionary<X, Y>::GenericDictionary(X MinValue, X MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions)

… where X and Y are concrete types. Note that the template preamble is now empty.
That’s a member function specialization. A specialization of the class would look like:
template<>
class GenericDictionary<X, Y>
{
    // ...

Again, note the template preamble is empty. Also note the new specialized template arguments come after the class name.
A partial specialization of the class would look something like:
template<typename A, typename B>
class GenericDictionary<A, B>
{
    // ...

In this case, the template preamble is not empty (and may have more or less parameters than the original template), but there are still template arguments after the class name.
Another kind of specialization uses concepts and constraint ordering:
template<typename T, typename U>
class GenericDictionary
{};

// This is more specialized than the previous.
template<typename T, typename U>
requires something
class GenericDictionary
{};

But that’s a whole other can of worms.
Bottom line is: I think you have confused out-of-class definitions for specializations. They can be (and any member function specialization must be out-of-class), but only if they start with an empty template preamble (template<>). (And in that case, you would usually need to provide the non-specialized definition somewhere, either in-class or out-of-class.)
Now if you’re asking whether defining member functions out of class is a problem… I’d say no. Personally, I prefer to keep everything in-class unless it gets monster huge (but in that case, it should probably be split into smaller functions anyway), or it should be in an implementation file (in which case it couldn’t be a template anyway). But I don’t really care if you prefer to define everything out-of-class.
Are there any C++ 20 concepts I could use to make the code shorter?
There are certainly a lot of ways concepts could help! And I’ll be pointing them out. However…:

The functions that error check for multiple enum usage, missing enums and multiple string usage come to mind for this question.

I can’t see how concepts would help with any of that stuff.
Concepts can really only constrain what types a template is instantiated with. It cannot do anything about the values that functions get. Concepts could certainly ensure that your constructor only gets a range of pairs of IDs and values… but they can’t do anything about what values are in that range. If there are duplicates or other wonky data in that range, concepts can’t help. Duplicate values or missing values are value errors (as the names imply); they are not type errors.
It may become clearer when I show you how concepts could actually help you out in the code review.
Code review
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
struct GenricDictionaryDataPair
{
    dictID id;
    dictName names;
};

This type doesn’t seem like it should be an independent type. It is never used anywhere publicly, not even in the interface of GenericDictionary. (DictType is, but probably doesn’t need to be.) It should probably be a member type of GenericDictionary, and a private one at that.
Also, as a style point, template parameters are conventionally capitalized (but not all caps, other than single-letter identifiers). So template<typename DictID, typename DictName>.
Also, you may have a typo there.
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
class GenericDictionary
{

Alright, let’s get some concepts up in here.
Now, as I understand it, the first template parameter for this type should always be an enumeration. The second could be anything—presumably std::string, but not necessarily. But if the first should always be an enumeration, then let’s make it so.
First, we need a concept that is only true for enumeration types:
template<typename T>
concept enumeration = std::is_enum_v<T>;

Now we just need to apply it:
template <enumeration dictID, typename dictName>
class GenericDictionary
{

Simple as that!
What about the second type? Well, it could be anything in theory, but there are some constraints. One is that it can’t be a reference type, because we can’t put those in a std::unordered_map. (Even if we could, what sense would that make?) It also obviously can’t be a function (though it could be a function pointer), and it obviously can’t be void. The standard library has a type trait that pretty well summarizes all this: std::is_object. So let’s use that.
Another constraint is that it should be hashable and equality comparable, because we need both of those properties to put it in a std::unordered_map. Now, technically, the right thing to do would be to provide the hashing and equality function objects as template parameters, like so:
template<
    enumeration E,
    typename V,
    typename VHash = std::hash<V>,
    typename VEqual = std::equal_to<T>
>
requires std::is_object_v<V>
    // plus checks that VHash and VEqual have the right signatures
class GenericDictionary

But if you’re just using the defaults, that’s fine, but we should at least check that they work:
template<
    enumeration E,
    typename V
>
requires std::is_object_v<V>
    and requires
        {
            typename std::hash<V>;
            typename std::equal_to<V>;
        }
class GenericDictionary

So if someone provides a value type that they didn’t make a hash function for, they will get a clear error message saying typename std::hash<V> failed.
If you don’t like the ad-hoc requirements, you could make a concept:
template<typename T>
concept generic_dictionary_value =
    std::is_object_v<T>
    and requires
        {
            typename std::hash<V>;
            typename std::equal_to<V>;
        }
;

template<enumeration E, generic_dictionary_value V>
class GenericDictionary
{
    // ...

Skipping down to the constructors:
    GenericDictionary()
    : MinimumValue{0},
      MaximumValue{0}
    {};

    GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue)
    : MinimumValue{MinValue},
      MaximumValue{MaxValue}
      {};

First, the semicolons here are unnecessary, and may trigger a warning (which can often break builds, because a lot of people turn warnings into errors).
Now, I get the desire to have no-fail constructors, but I don’t agree with having “constructors” that leave objects in an uninitialized state. That really kinda defeats the purpose of constructors. We’ll get into this shortly, but you’ll find that something like 70% of the complexity of your class stems from the fact that it can exist in broken states. That’s just bad on a lot of levels. A well-designed class should NEVER be in a broken state.
(With one and only one exception: when it has just been moved-from. A moved-from object should be safely re-assignable and destructable, and nothing else. This is never a problem, because no one should ever do anything else with a moved-from object, and static analyzers can trivially detect if an object that has been moved from is used in any way other than being re-assigned or destroyed.)
So what’s the solution here? Well, I would suggest doing something like this:
template <typename dictID, typename dictName>
class GenericDictionary
{
public:
    static auto create_with_definitions(std::ranges::input_range auto&& definitions)
        -> std::expected<GenericDictionary, /* some error type */>
    {
        // "internal" is a tag to select a private constructor that
        // doesn't do full initialization.
        auto dict = GenericDictionary{internal};

        // Now do your initialization, and if there is an error,
        // return std::unexpected{/*error code*/}.
        //
        // If not, return dict.
    }

    GenericDictionary(std::ranges::input_range&& definitions)
    {
        // Do your initialization, and if there is an error, throw.
    }

private:
    // Internal-only constructor that doesn't fully initialize.
    explicit GenericDictionary(internal_t) {}
};

Now there is no possible way for client code to create an uninitialized or invalid dictionary. There are basically two ways to create a dictionary:
auto dict = GenericDictionary{data}; // might throw

// OR:

auto dict = GenericDictionary::create_with_definitions(data); // should not throw (this is a lie!!!)
if (dict)
    use(*dict);
else
    // there was an error

// Or with monadic ops:
GenericDictionary::create_with_definitions(data)
    .and_then(use)
    .or_else(report_error)
;

Now, all that being said… all these acrobatics to avoid exceptions are ultimately pointless, because you cannot avoid exceptions. No matter what you do, even if all the data is perfectly kosher, the std::unordered_maps can still throw exceptions.
In fact:
// Safe constructor that will not throw exceptions, but the search table is
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    |
                                    +------ ORLY?
// not initialized.
    GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue)
    : MinimumValue{MinValue},
      MaximumValue{MaxValue}
      {};

That constructor implicitly calls the std::unordered_map default constructor… twice. But Indi, you say, it’s the std::unordered_map default constructor! It doesn’t do anything! The map is empty after it’s done! Is that so, I say in way that makes it clear it is very much not so. Look more closely. It turns out the default constructor constructs an implementation-defined number of buckets. Unlike, say, std::vector’s default constructor, which is (mostly) specified not to throw, the std::unordered_map constructor makes no such guarantees.
So matter what you do, you cannot avoid exceptions. (Not that that should be a concern. Contrary to decades of myth, exceptions are generally more efficient than manual checks.)
That doesn’t necessarily mean you need to give up. There are cases where you can and should avoid exceptions—mostly situations where problems are expected, and not exceptional situations. I don’t see that being the case here. Even if you do all the checks to ensure the enumerators are contiguous, and that there are no duplicates—which, I remind you, I am suggesting you not do—those should not be considered regularly expected problems. It’s not something that, if it happens, you just go, oops, let me try again; it’s a pretty damn hard error that you can pretty much only fix by rewriting the friggin’ source code. Failing those checks should indeed be an exceptional situation. So don’t fear exceptions. Don’t try to dance around them. Just throw.
    GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions);

I’m not really sure this constructor makes a lot of sense.
It would be really cool if you could just do:
auto d = GenericDictionary{
    {e::v1, "s1"},
    {e::v2, "s2"},
    // ...
};

But off the top of my head, I can’t see a way to make that work. At the very least you need to provide some help to deduction:
// either:
auto d = GenericDictionary<e, std::string>{
    {e::v1, "s1"},
    {e::v2, "s2"},
    // ...
};
// or:
auto d = GenericDictionary{
    GenricDictionaryDataPair{e::v1, "s1"},
    GenricDictionaryDataPair{e::v2, "s2"},
    // ...
};

So you might as well just forget about initializer lists and do:
auto d = GenericDictionary{std::to_array<std::pair<e, std::string>>({
    {e::v1, "s1"},
    {e::v2, "s2"},
    // ...
})};

Interestingly, that might actually be more efficient, because the initializer list has const elements, and so requires copying, while the array allows moving.
And, let’s be real, what’s in the dictionary isn’t GenricDictionaryDataPairs in any case. So… it’s not even a real initializer list.
So, I’d suggest just ditching the initializer list constructor.
    GenericDictionary(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::vector<DictType> definitions);

This constructor takes a std::vector by value, forcing a copy. That is wholly unnecessary. One of your member functions actually gets it right: take an input range reference. Like so:
    GenericDictionary(std::ranges::input_range auto&& definitions);

Except you could constrain it better.
You don’t really need the input range to have GenricDictionaryDataPairs. All you need are 2-tuples, where the first element is the enumeration and the second is convertible to the value type.
So:
template<typename R>
requires std::ranges::input_range<R>
    and (std::tuple_size_v<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>> == 2>
    and std::convertible<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>, dictID>
    and std::convertible<std::tuple_element_t<1, std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>, dictName>
GenericDictionary(R&& definitions);

Something like that.
    virtual ~GenericDictionary() = default;

    virtual dictID getIds(dictName itemName);
    virtual dictName getNames(dictID id);

I honestly don’t see the sense of virtual functions here. You say that this is just the “base for more complex object”, and that if you want “{m}ore complex objects than strings” then “overrides will be necessary”. What kind of more complex objects would require overriding anything here? What possible behavioural changes could anyone even do to getIds() and getNames()? I mean, the way the data is encoded in the type is already set in stone (the “add” functions are not virtual, and the maps are already specified (and they should not be protected, by the way)), so what other ways of “getting” values out of the two maps are there?
Frankly I see no purpose for polymorphism here. If for whatever reason someone wants to do further computations on the ID or value they “got” out of the bi-map, then the proper way to do that would be encapsulation… not inheritance. In other words, wrap the dictionary, and then provide whatever modified behaviour you want around the dictionary calls.
Generally speaking, non-abstract base classes are a code smell. And this type makes no sense as an abstract base class. A dictionary is not an abstract concept, it is quite concrete. A good test for an abstract type is when someone says “I have a X”, you have to ask “what kind of X” (“I have an animal”→“what kind of animal?”; “I have a shape”→“what kind of shape?”). When someone says “I have a dictionary mapping enumerations to strings”, “what kind of dictionary mapping enumerations to strings” is hardly a sensible follow-up question. (Pretty much the only way to answer that question is: “the kind that does exactly what it says in its name, dipshit”.)
Back to the functions, the two “get” functions should probably be const. And I’m not sure “get” is the right name. You don’t really “get” things out of a dictionary (Python notwithstanding). “Lookup” or “find” seem more appropriate. The standard maps all just use operator[]. You could too, except it’s not suited for error cases, and it won’t work if the key and value are the same type.
    bool addAllDefinitions(std::ranges::input_range auto&& definitions);
    bool addAllDefinitions(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::ranges::input_range auto&& definitions);
    bool addAllDefinitions(std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions);
    bool addAllDefinitions(dictID MinValue, dictID MaxValue, std::initializer_list<DictType> definitions);

These functions are all superfluous. The constructor should do this job.
    void enableExceptions(bool exceptionsEnabled) { throwException = exceptionsEnabled; };

Exceptions are enabled no matter what you do.
Also, the only place this seems to have relevance is in the functions that initialize the dictionary. But that should only be done in the constructor, which makes this function too little too late.
#ifdef GD_UNIT_TEST
    std::vector<DictType> getUserInput() const noexcept { return userInputList; }
    bool selfUnitTest();
#endif

So let’s get the immediate problems out of the way first. The getUserInput() function is never used. It serves absolutely no purpose. (I can also add that it seems wildly optimistic to believe that a function that returns a vector by copy would be noexcept.)
As for userInputList… I’m truly baffled by this. In your initialization functions, you copy all the input data into this vector… and then copy it again into the actual maps. Why not just copy directly into the maps in one step? And even if there were any reason to copy to a vector first… why keep it around?
I can see that you use it in some of the check functions that the initialization functions use, but again… why keep it around once the checks are done?
As for selfUnitTest()… no, just no. That is so very, very wrong. Tests should not ever be inside the system-under-test. Before the tests run, you have no idea if the system is completely borked… but if the system is completely borked, then how can you trust the tests inside the system? And if the test is failing, is it because the system is bad on its own or is the test breaking it?
In the first place, tests should be written before the system being tested. If the tests are inside the thing being tested… you have some temporal causality issues to deal with.
Also, one of the fundamentals of unit testing is that you are only supposed to be testing the public interface. If something is only observable inside the system-under-test, then it is functionally irrelevant to the rest of the world. You might argue “but something inside might have an impact on the outside!” To which I would respond: then it would not be “only observable inside”, and we can test those outside observations.
I would go even further and say that a class’s unit tests should not only not be inside the class, they shouldn’t even be in the header file? Why? Because if you add new tests, you would break existing builds; everyone would have to recompile perfectly good code for no good reason. It actually goes both ways: you should be free to hack away at the tests without impacting the system (or its users), and changes to the system should not impact the tests (unless a regression was introduced, naturally). It should be safe to refactor the system without doing any damage to the tests, but you can’t be sure of that if the system and tests are woven together.
At least no testing is actually being done by selfUnitTest(), although the actual unit tests should not be in the header file. That would actually help remove quite a bit of cruft from the header, too. You won’t need <iostream> anymore, for example.
#ifdef DEBUG
    void debugDumpData() const noexcept;
    void debugDumpUserList() noexcept { debugDumpList(userInputList); };
    void debugDumpList(std::vector<DictType> candidate) noexcept;
#endif // DEBUG

Well, given that userInputList shouldn’t exist, that means debugDumpUserList() shouldn’t exist either. And since debugDumpList() is only used by debugDumpUserList(), that can go too. That just leaves debugDumpData().
That might be worth leaving, though I would have it take a std::ostream& rather than hard-coding std::cerr. I would also not bother conditionally compiling it. Why add the extra complexity? Template functions are not instantiated unless used, so if no one does any debug dumping, it’s absolutely harmless to leave it. And if someone does do debug dumping… well, then who cares whether they’ve defined DEBUG or not?
Consider that for every conditional compilation branch in your code, you need to run another CI instance for every single platform. Your code is supposed to compile with GCC and Clang on Windows, Mac, and Linux? That’s 6 CI instances. Oh, the code is different depending on whether DEBUG is defined? Now you have 12 instances. Oh, there’s another conditional compilation macro in there? 24. And another? Now it’s 48. It’s a combinatorial explosion. (And we only started with 6. In a lot of cases, you want to support GCC and Clang… with different versions. So a lot of times you’re starting with a dozen CI instances, and then you get the combinatorial explosion on top of that.)
(Also, if anything you might want to invert the logic, and check whether NDEBUG is not defined, because NDEBUG is standard, while DEBUG is not.)
    [[nodiscard]] bool commonInternalListBuilder(std::string funcName) noexcept;

So, to start, this really shouldn’t be a protected function. There is no reason for derived classes to construct the guts of a dictionary. They couldn’t even if they wanted to; most (all?) of the functions used by commonInternalListBuilder() are not virtual.
(Indeed, protected functions—protected anything—in general is a code smell. Unless you have specific reasons to leave the private guts of your class hanging out and open to abuse… don’t. Don’t just do because “I dunno, because maybe?”.)
Also, there is no way in hell a function that initializes two hash maps is noexcept.
Now, you pass around a string (by value) as a poor man’s way of having some kind of stack trace, but there are better solutions. The first is std::source_location, which would give more information, be more automatic, and be cheaper than a string. And then there’s std::stacktrace.
Finally, you just return bool, missing a glorious opportunity to provide more information about the error. commonInternalListBuilder() can fail in at least a half-dozen ways, but you just throw away the information about what the failure was and what triggered it.
    [[nodiscard]] bool sanityCheck(std::string funcName, std::string searchValue) noexcept;

This is a huge code smell, because if *this is not sane, how can you be sure this->sanityCheck() is sane?
The general rule in class design is to never let a member function leave the class in an invalid state. If you follow that rule, you never need to check at the start of a member function whether the class is in an invalid state… because it never will be. The class should be sane from the moment the first constructor completes… or an exception should be thrown if it cannot… and it should remain sane until the destructor call. If at any point you need to temporarily break the class invariants, you must rollback (the strong guarantee) or otherwise put the class in a sane state (the weak guarantee) before you report the error (by exception or whatever). Any class that does not follow these rules is at best dangerous, and at worst, unusable.
Just consider: if you allow, in any way, a member function to end with the class not in a perfectly legit state, how can you be sure sanityCheck() will detect the problem? After all, you don’t check every possible “insane” state there, now do you? (And even if you tried to, you probably won’t think of every way things could go wrong… and even if you could, the costs would probably be prohibitive.)
So basically, you shouldn’t need this function. If you think you do, you have bigger problems than this function could ever hope to fix.
I think that’s about it, except to note that not only should the unit tests be moved out of the header, they should be written using a proper testing framework. Hand-rolled tests are smelly, because they usually require more complicated code… and now you have to ask whether the tests need testing. Using a framework, virtually all of your tests are ~3–5 lines, no branches or loops, with every step clear as crystal:
test("whatever") {
    // setup

    // action being tested

    // assertion(s)
}

And if the tests are comprehensive and isolated from the system, you can fearlessly hack away at the system refactoring recklessly and shaving away every little inefficiency. That’s how you get code that is confidently correct and efficient.

When I mentioned concepts I wasn't thinking std::concepts. My bad. What I mean was is there any C++ technology (template, class, methods) that could shorten that code.

Yes, you understand the goal of the code.

I have created a chat room specifically for this question and related questions and for the answers to those questions. I'd like you to join the discussion. I find your answers quite educational.

protected: versus private: Good catch, left over from when I was trying to make this an abstract class.

std::expected and std::unexpected are C++23 features. I don't believe they are available in C++20.

An implementation of the expected monad was standardized in C++23, but the idea has been around since at least C++11. If you want to use expected monad error handling, it’s really easy to roll your own, and even make it so you can transparently interoperate with or switch to std::expected when C++23 is available. But, honestly, I don’t see the point here; pretty much any errors that happen here are going to be compile-time logic errors, and functionally unrecoverable. Exceptions just make more sense.

Just FYI, the original version had no error checking. It was pointed out in 2 of the 4 reviews that it might need error checking. The use of std::unordered_map was added for the same reason. The most recent version has been changed to C++23 to make use of some of the features. It no longer requires the special format of the enum.

I'm curious about what you think about just performing the error checking when it is compiled -g (NDEBUG in gcc, _DEUBG in visual studio)? This would make the error checking more like an assert() I have modified the code to check for both NDEBUG and _DEBUG for the debug code.

I think you need to tighten up your terminology, because the kind of “error” assert() is meant to check isn’t even in the same category as the kind of “error” std::expected is for. Also, standard C’s NDEBUG macro, GCC’s -g option, and Visual Studio’s _DEBUG compiler intrinsic are all different things, that all do different things, (mostly) unrelated to each other. Which one is correct in your case? Depends what you mean by “error checking”.

I was only discussing the errors that throw exceptions in the constructor. Returning std::unexpected for items not found then makes sense. From what I've read so far on the Internet, Visual Studio _DEBUG and !NDEBUG are equivalent. Can you point me to some documentation that doesn't agree with that?

Where on earth did you find someone saying they’re “equivalent”? I just tried googling “NDEBUG versus _DEBUG”, and the first 4 answers explain that they are different. The 5th is a VS documentation page about _DEBUG that doesn’t mention NDEBUG at all. The 6th is an O’Reilly C++ book page about NDEBUG that doesn’t mention _DEBUG at all. And the 7th is a detailed blog post about debugging options and why “debug build” is a nonsensical concept (also doesn’t mention _DEBUG directly, but does refer to its effects).
